# Google tag manager not sending analytics request after route changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement google tag manager in react application. It works on page reload, but when I move between my application through routes, it does not register a page view in google analytics.

I have tried `react-gtm-module`, but it is also working on reload and not on route changes.

`index.html`
added below code in `head` tag.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

added below code in `body` tag.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

and inside my components `componentDidMount`, I am pushing new `pageView` in `dataLayer`

```
dataLayer.push({
    event: 'Pageview',
    pagePath: 'page-path-here',
    pageTitle: 'page-title-here',
});
```

I have created `pagePath` and `pageTitle` dataLayer variables and a assigned them to Google analytics tag.I have also created a custom trigger`PageView` and added it to firing triggers in Google analytics tag.

Data layer variables
[image: data layer variables list]

Custom triggers
[image: custom trigger]

Assignment of data layer variables to Analytics tag
[image: google analytics data layer variables]

Can anyone please point me in correct direction?

**Edit:**
Detail Data layer variable view
[image: google analytics data layer variables detai]

First load (reload)
[image: google analytics data layer variables detai]

Route change
[image: google analytics data layer variables detai]

Comment: The setup seems to be correct, although the detailed settings of the variables are not included in the post. What do you see in the GTM debug view? Do you see the event? What are the values of the variables? What tags are fired?

Comment: @kgrg I can see the event being sent in on first load. Routing change is not firing pageView trigger. Do I need to do anything after pushing into dataLayer like call any tagmanager function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `componentDidMount` code to

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'Pageview',
    pagePath: 'page-path-here',
    pageTitle: 'page-title-here',
});
```

[Datalayer push](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/datalayer-push/)

Now I can see page views in Google Analytics on route changes.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written in `index.html` only runs once when the page is loaded if you want to register an event on page change you need to trigger the same on the routes you want to trigger, you can access the `dataLayer` variable from `window`